# A problem when adds class to top links

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to add a class to top links and in custom theme, I print it out.

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Create account</label>
            <url>customer/account/create</url>
            <!-- can use full url also -->
            <title>Create account</title>
            <prepare>true</prepare>
            <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
            <urlParams/>
            <liParams>class="li-create-account"</liParams>
            <aParams>class="a-create-account"</aParams>
            <position>90</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

I print it like that

```
<?php echo $_link->getLiParams(); ?> 
<?php echo $_link->getAParams(); ?>
```

But the thing is, `$_link->getLiParams()` shows `a-create-account` instead of `li-create-account`. And `$_link->getAParams()` shows 90.

Does anybody know what I did wrong here? any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to print it a different way as the parameters are rendered by the block.

You can use the following code

```
 <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>Test</label>
                <url>>customer/account/create</url>
                <title>Test</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>100</position>
                <liParams><class>li-create-account</class></liParams>
                <aParams><class>a-create-account</class></aParams>
            </action>
```

Comment: I tried it before then I got this error :    `code` Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty  in /private/var/www/top-sport/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php on line 244  I don't know why it happened in this way.

Comment: @Tran I forgot to close a tag see my updated answer

Comment: Still an extra closing bracket on <url>>.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, in your `local.xml`

```
<customer_logged_out>
<reference name="top.links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>About Us</label>
    <url>about-us</url>
    <title>About Us</title>
    <prepare>true</prepare>
    <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/>
    <position>1</position>
    <liParams>id="about-us-li"</liParams>
    <aParams>class="top-link" id="about-us-top-link"</aParams>
    <beforeText/>
    <afterText>|</afterText>
</action>
</reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

For more check this link : http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/adding-custom-links-local-xml/

Comment: thanks other guy a bit faster but still appreciate your help.